# Alternatives for a UDN2981A

Tags: components, current-source, led-matrix, alternatives

I'm making the circuit [depicted here](https://youtu.be/wXvs0CrRPIw?t=7m4s).

I already have the shift registers I require, but I can't find any UDN2981A ICs in the stores I have available to me. Unfortunately, I don't have time to wait for shipping from an online store.

1) Are there alternatives to the UDN2981A I could try? (I've already checked UDN2981A, UDN2982A, UDN2982LW, and A2982SLW, none of them are available)

2) Can I use discrete transistors to substitute the UDN2981A? Which kind do I need?

3) Are there any completely different circuits I could try finding parts for and building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

- Replace your low-side shift registers with a LED constant current sink shift register like the STP16CP05
- Do away with all the current limiting resistors - just have the current set resistor for the constant current sink
- Use discrete (or multi-pack) PNP or P-channel MOSFETs for the anodes, or a high current shift register source (not constant current, just any shift register that can source larger currents).